# Karate JSON object is not instanceof Object - What is it then and how to fix?

Tags: karate

Very simple: my JavaScript based application handles a JSON payload and checks for the variable type as follows and this works like a charm:

```js
if(obj instanceof Object) {
  // handle JSON payload
} else {
  throw new Error("no JSON payload");
}
```

Now, when I use Karate to test some JSON payloads against my application then this type check fails - likely because a JSON or object defined in a feature is of a different type.

**Problem:** Karate does not work with my app, or I would need to rewrite code in my app to make the type check working with Karate JSON objects = not good.

**Solution:** What type is it and how could I check for it? See further examples below.

For example, a mismatch shows type `"MAP"`:

```py
Feature: Mismatch

Scenario: MAP type
    * def o = {foo:"bar"}
    * match o == true
```

Result (error):

```
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | data types don't match (MAP:BOOLEAN)
  {"foo":"bar"}
  true
```

Example:

```py
Feature: Code

Background:
    * def instanceOf = obj => obj instanceof Object

Scenario: Run pure ES6 JavaScript code in GraalVM
    * eval
    """
    const pureInstanceOf = obj => obj instanceof Object;
    inLineObj = {foo:{bar:"baz"}};
    karate.log(`pure inLineObj: ${pureInstanceOf(inLineObj)}`); // true
    karate.log(`inLineObj: ${instanceOf(inLineObj)}`); // false
    multiLineJson = {
      "foo": {
        "bar": "baz"
      }
    };
    karate.log(`pure multiLineJson: ${pureInstanceOf(multiLineJson)}`); // true
    karate.log(`multiLineJson: ${instanceOf(multiLineJson)}`); // false
    """

Scenario: Karate JSON type
    * def inLineObj = {foo:{bar:"baz"}}
    * def test = instanceOf(inLineObj)
    * match test == true
    
    * def multiLineJson =
    """
    {
      "foo": {
        "bar": "baz"
      }
    }
    """
    * def test = instanceOf(multiLineJson)
    * match test == true
```

When I run this using Karate's standalone JAR, the result is:

```
15:53:59.945 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - ===================================================================
15:53:59.984 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - pure inLineObj: true
15:53:59.993 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - inLineObj: false
15:53:59.994 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - pure multiLineJson: true
15:53:59.995 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - multiLineJson: false
15:54:00.001 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - ===================================================================
15:54:00.050 [main]  ERROR com.intuit.karate - code.feature:27
* match test == true
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal (BOOLEAN:BOOLEAN)
  false
  true

code.feature:27
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: code.feature
scenarios:  2 | passed:  1 | failed:  1 | time: 0,0653
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to run `obj instanceof Object` in pure JavaScript in the GraalVM engine and did the same in a Karate feature doing it the Karate-way (using `* def`).

I expect the same results but this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this already helps a bit to see clearer.

So I could check it in Karate (using `* eval code`) as well as in my JS app as follows:

```js
obj instanceof Java.type('java.util.Map')
```

(I also tried `obj instanceof Java.type('java.util.LinkedHashMap')` but it's only working in Karate using `* eval code` but not within my JS app)

Working example:

```py
Feature: Karate JSON type

Background:
    * def karateInstanceOf = obj => obj instanceof Object ? "Object" : obj instanceof Java.type('java.util.Map') ? "Map" : "other"

Scenario: The pure JavaScript way (GraalVM engine)
    * eval
    """
    const jsInstanceOf = obj => obj instanceof Object ? "Object" : obj instanceof Java.type('java.util.Map') ? "Map" : "other";
    
    let json = {foo:"bar"};
    karate.log(`jsInstanceOf: ${jsInstanceOf(json)}`); // "Object"
    karate.log(`karateInstanceOf: ${karateInstanceOf(json)}`); // "Map"
    """

Scenario: The Karate way
    * def json = {foo:"bar"}
    * def test = karateInstanceOf(json)
    * match test == "Map"
```

Result:

```
17:13:15.505 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - jsInstanceOf: Object
17:13:15.514 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - karateInstanceOf: Map
17:13:15.521 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - ===================================================================
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: code.feature
scenarios:  2 | passed:  2 | failed:  0 | time: 0,0535
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think I kinda "abuse" Karate to make it work with my existing JavaScript... but it's working and is actually very useful if you're not a Java developer. Sorry for that.

I wanted to avoid karate-specific code in my JS app, so I finally could fix it using
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( ... ))` as follows:

```py
Feature: Karate JSON actually is a 'java.util.Map'

Background:
    * eval
    """
    my_app = obj => obj instanceof Object ? "good" : "bad";
    // of course, I'm doing this ^^ in a smarter way
    """

Scenario: Convert 'java.util.Map' to native JavaScript object
    * def json = {foo:"bar"}
    * eval result = my_app(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)))
    * match result == "good"
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Karate is not designed to work with existing JS or Java. The principle is you should simulate what your end-users or API consumers are doing: which is JSON over HTTP.

That said, Karate has a few helpers that you can use, but I'd like to emphasize that this is normally not done in tests.

```
if (karate.typeOf(obj) === 'map') {}
```

And the possible values are `list`, `xml` and `string`. Kinda convenient to distinguish between Objects and Arrays if you need to.

Recent versions of Karate had a bug for the JS "compatibility" so watch out for that: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2224

Anything beyond this, please assume is not supported in Karate. But we welcome code-contributions.